# How can i avoid the permalink start with 'blog' while using the custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, 404-error

I used the custom Structure `/blog/%category%/%postname%/` for blog. also i have a custom post type named 'FAQ' while viewing the faq posts, it is showing the `/blog/faq/%faq_category%/%postname%/`. When I'm using the `['with_front' => false]` the paged URLs ('Old entries' and 'New entries' links) `http://www.example.com/faq/page/2/` are always showing the **404 page**.

Comment: You question was moved here to WPSE by SO. I noticed that you don't have an account here, so feel free to register an account here so that you will be able to participate with others in trying to solve your problem. You might also want to check out our [tour] page and visit [help] to learn how this site operates. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2):

This can be set in a plugins' options if you're using a plugin to generate a Custom Post Type (such as CPT UI).

Otherwise if you've created this post type in the functions.php file you should amend or add to your your code as follows:

```
'with_front' => false
```

i.e. if your permalink structure appears as:

```
yourwebsite.co.uk/blog/custom-post-title
```

then setting this to 'false' will make your url something like:

```
yourwebsite.co.uk/custom-post-title
```

Comment: Hi Adam, I tried this before but the problem is, i also required the custom post type with paging. means 'Old entries' and 'New entries' links. when i using the ['with_front' => false] the paged url always showing the 404 page

Comment: Have you tried flushing the permalinks? Just resave them to refresh them.

Comment: Hi Adam, i flushed the permalinks using the flush_rewrite_rules(); I got removed the 404 page and show rest of the posts but when open the details page it's going to 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

With custom post types, **has_archive** defaults to false - this will need to be explicitly set to true.

Also, in your **rewrite** argument, you might need to set:

```
'pages' => true
```

'pages' should default to true, but might need to be explicitly set if you've switched it off elsewhere?

Finally, if you are registering the post type inside of a plugin, call flush_rewrite_rules() in your activation and deactivation hook.

I hope this helps! All the details about these arguments can be found here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type